IF(ISNUMBER( Search cell from table and return item on table
I want to search J2 for a section of text that would match any of the items in a list (B25:B34), and if there is a match, I want A2 to return whichever one of those items were matched.
ie.
Cell to be searched
J2: The quick brown fox
J3: The lazy dog
List to match against
B25: brown fox
B26: lazy dog
B27: fat cat
......
Desired result
A2: brown fox
A3: lazy dog
I'd like to avoid having to add multiple formulas to each cell in the A column for every individual item in my B25:B34 list, but I'm not sure how.
Right now, =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B25,J2)),B25,"")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B26,J2),B26,"")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B27,J2)B27,"").... etc. works well, but the formula will get huge as my list grows.
Is there a more elegant way of getting this done?
Thank you!

You can use a shortened version of your formula for A2:
=CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$25:$B$34,J2)),T(+$B$25:$B$34),""))


Try something along the lines :


=LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(" "&B$25:B$34&" "," "&J2&" "),B$25:B$34)


Or, and if you using MS365 and while writing if you have enabled the Office Insiders then could use REGEXTEST() as well:
=LET(α, B$25:B$34, XLOOKUP(1,N(REGEXTEST(J2,"\b"&α&"\b")),α))


The word-boundaries should ensure that we do not match any false positives. The documentation for the not widely available function one can read here REGEXTEST()

